# Kivy GUI cannot run together with Listeners

Tags: python, kivy, listener, kivy-language, kivymd

**Kivy GUI does not run together with listeners**. I'm a newbie Python coder, I would appreciate any kind of help given as I am stuck on this problem for a quite awhile. I am thinking of the **multithreading** and **multiprocessing**. Thank you in advance!

```
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from pynput.mouse import Listener as MouseListener
from pynput.keyboard import Listener as KeyboardListener
from threading import Thread


# some functions over here
def on_press(key):
    print(key)


def on_release(key):
    pass


def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    pass


def microphone():
    pass


# my Kivy designs such as buttons stored (on a .kv file)
class KivyFile(Widget):
    # Some methods over here
    pass


# Build the Kivy GUI
class KivyGUI(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return KivyFile()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Set up the listener threads
    keyboard_listener = KeyboardListener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release)
    mouse_listener = MouseListener(on_click=on_click)
    record_audio_thread = Thread(target=microphone)

    # Start the threads and join them so the script doesn't end unexpectedly
    record_audio_thread.start()
    keyboard_listener.start()
    mouse_listener.start()
    keyboard_listener.join()
    mouse_listener.join()

    KivyGUI().run()
```

With this code, `KivyGUI().run()` cannot run the GUI as it will get stuck due to the listeners. But if I run the Kivy GUI first as below: (The GUI will be displayed but the listeners won't work anymore

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    KivyGUI().run()
    
    # Set up the listener threads
    keyboard_listener = KeyboardListener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release)
    mouse_listener = MouseListener(on_click=on_click)
    record_audio_Thread = Thread(target=microphone)

    # Start the threads and join them so the script doesn't end unexpectedly
    record_audio_Thread.start()
    keyboard_listener.start()
    mouse_listener.start()
    keyboard_listener.join()
    mouse_listener.join()
```

Comment: When you call `join()` on a thread, you are waiting for that thread to complete, so nothing after that will be run until that thread completes. (same for `App.run()`). Try removing the calls to `join()`.

Comment: Thank you @JohnAnderson for the insight (removing the ```join()```), I've tried that previously but it doesn't seem to work and I thought it wasn't the problem here. But after seeing your comment I've decided to give it a few more tries **(by starting the listeners first then the Kivy GUI)**. If I start the Kivy GUI first, the listeners will not start! Thank you so much it is now working. Maybe you can leave an answer below so I can mark it as a correct answer, thank you again.